# PHP CLI APPCRASH con ImageMagick

Tags: php, sql-server, imagemagick

Escribí un script en PHP que convierte una serie de archivos TIFF en PDF.

Dejé corriendo el script por varias horas, luego de migrar con éxito cientos de items el CLI de PHP ha dejado de funcionar y lanza el siguiente registro de error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: php.exe
  Application Version:  7.0.32.0
  Application Timestamp:    5b999a35
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.24308
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5be8601e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000002a365
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 12ce
  Additional Information 2: 12ce3e17db77b844c7e0ababa92509a2
  Additional Information 3: 28ca
  Additional Information 4: 28cad64ec5ba6edc5f3fc55b5bff9648
```

Esta es la porción de código que con algunos archivos TIFF da error:

```
// Saving every page of a TIFF as PDF
                $original_image = new Imagick($originalFile); //multipage tiff

                $result = new Imagick(); // result object

                $original_image->setImageFormat("pdf");
                $result->addImage( $original_image ); 


                if (!$result->writeImages($newpath, true)) {
                    echo "Error on copy $originalFile...\n";
                }
                else{
                    echo $originaldocpath . "\n -> (". $newpath .")\n";
                }
```

Al clickear sobre el botón "Debug error" en la ventana de windows que me informa de la APPCRASH me abre una nueva ventana que dice: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in php.exe [29472].

Estoy corriendo PHP 7.0.32.0 en Windows SERVER 2008 R2 Standard, usando como base de datos SQL Server 2014.

Quisiera saber cómo eludir el error y así poder procesar toda la tabla items.

Comment: existe algo llamdado `try catch` que es para atrapar esto errores y no detener la ejecucion del mismo! otra seria ver cual es el archivo especifico que genera dicho error puede que el formato pasado no sea el adecuado!

Comment: gracias, voy a ponerlo en un bloque try catch. de miles de archivos procesados con éxito solamente 4 me dieron error. Voy a abrir los TIFF originales y se abren sin problema, asi que descarto un error en el archivo de origen, me temo que puede ser mas bien una limitacion de la version de imagemagick que estoy usando

Comment: puedes procesarlos por etapas primero 100 luego 100 y asi sucesivamente! a ver si asi te deja!

Comment: Si asi lo hago,los proceso por lotes, eso me permitió identificar exactamente cuáles eran los archivos problemáticos.